# Почему метки "жаргон" и "сленг" - синонимы?

Tags: предложение

Метки "жаргон" и "сленг" объявлены синонимами; более того, "жаргон" - основная метка. Я бы оставил  "жаргон" для "речи какой-л. социальной или профессиональной группы", а "сленг" - для повсеместно распространенных "элементов речи, не совпадающих с нормой литературного языка". В крайнем случае, можно считать, что понятие "сленг" включает и "жаргон", но не наоборот; тогда "сленг" надо сделать основной меткой.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37443/Жаргон-и-сленг-одно-и-то-же-или-нет вопрос про отличия жаргона и сленга. Там есть и мой ответ. С тех пор я мнение не поменял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько причин тому, что метки "жаргон" и "сленг" объединены:

1. Трудно провести грань между этими двумя понятиями. Если и проводить, то это приведет к путанице: простые пользователи будут ломать голову, каждый раз выбирая нужную метку.
2. Нет общепринятой точки зрения. Некоторые ученые используют эти термины синонимично, некоторые — пытаются провести смысловые границы.